# use of UDP in DNS

Tags: networking, protocol

**UDP** provides *no guarantee for delivery and no protection from duplication and is connection-less protocol* but why then DNS uses UDP protocol. Please make me clarify.

At what conditions we should prefer UDP over TCP protocol?

Comment: Did you try googling for "udp vs tcp"?  One of the top hits - [http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP](http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP) looks like it answers your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about networking than programming.

Comment: Network protocols *are* programming.  Protocols incorporate states & transitions, concurrency, algorithms, ...

Comment: The choice of a suitable protocol for an application is a programmer / programming decision.

Answer (score 7):

> UDP provides no guarantee for delivery and no protection from duplication and is connection-less protocol but why then DNS uses UDP protocol.

Because, despite having no delivery guarantees, UDP is a *good fit* for what the DNS protocol requires<sup>1</sup>.  In particular:

- DNS needs to be really fast.  Setting up a TCP connection requires an extra packet exchange.  Ditto for shutting down a TCP connection.
- A typical DNS request fits into a single network packet
- A typical DNS response fits into a single network packet
- Since DNS is a stateless protocol, resending a request after a timeout is not problematic.

> At what conditions we should prefer UDP over TCP protocol?

When the application / application-level protocol do not require the various nice (but relatively expensive) properties that a TCP transport layer provides.

It is theoretically possible<sup>2</sup> to implement all of the desirable features of TCP using an application-level protocol using UDP.  But sensible people don't .. because that would be wasted effort.

---

<sup>1 - In fact DNS can use TCP as well as UDP: [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Protocol_transport).</sup>

<sup>2 - In practice, there are likely to be issues due to differences in the way that UDP & TCP is handled by networks and OS kernels, kernel vs user space overheads, and so on.  Addressing these issues is ... complex.</sup>